# Unable to return a JSONObject field of a class properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a DTO like below:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LightRoundResponse {
    private String round;
    private JSONObject fields;
}
```

I am able to store and fetch the JSON Object from the DB. After setting DTO's fields attribute with the ResultSet's fields, I am able to see the JSONObject containing the correct data while debugging.

However the response which I get is:

```
{
    "round": "A Round",
    "fields": {
        "empty": false
    }
}
```

fields object is incorrect, I think since it's a JSONObject it could be an issue but I am not sure.
How can I get the correct response and not `"empty": false`

Comment: What is your expactation?

Comment: How to get the response correctly ?
"empty": false 
is definitely incorrect.
 I want to get the correct JSON Response !

Comment: it depends on why the jsonObject contains

Comment: @Jens any data in JSON format, what data shouldn't matter right ? That's why it's JSON, I don't have any format.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson does not know how to serialize `JSONObject` class. The expected way to do that is to actually use `Map<String, Object>`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LightRoundResponse {
    private String round;
    private Map<String, Object> fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting the JSONObject to Map does the job.

Example:

```
public class LightRoundResponse {
    private String round;
    private Map fields;

    public void setFields(JSONObject fields){
        this.fields = fields.toMap();
    }
}
```

I hope I could understand why JSONObject doesn't works, but seems like the community isn't aware also.
Hence posting a workaround, could help people facing the same issue.